# How to place profile picture image on that place in Android?

Tags: java, android

In my app, I want to put an image on the place where a user image is selected. In my fragment, I have one image view and one button, when I select an image from the gallery I cannot place the image on the Image View.

Here is my code:

Profile Fragment:

```js
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    //private static Bitmap Image = null;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;

    Button browseProfilePic;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_profilepic, container, false);
        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        browseProfilePic = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_pick);
        browseProfilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
                    try {
                        final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        final InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My activity:

```js
public class AccountActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.account);
        String item = getIntent().getStringExtra("item");
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch(item) {
            case "Balance": fragment = new BalanceFragment(); break;
            case "Personal": fragment = new PersonalFragment(); break;
            case "Work": fragment = new WorkFragment(); break;
            case "Address": fragment = new AddAddressFragment(); break;
            case "Vehicle": fragment = new AddVehicleFragment(); break;
            case "Preference": fragment = new PreferenceFragment(); break;
            case "About": fragment = new AboutFragment(); break;
            case "Settings": fragment = new SettingsFragment(); break;
            case "Help": fragment = new HelpFragment(); break;
            case "Profile":fragment = new ProfileFragment(); break;
            case "Logout":logout();break;
            default: fragment = new DefaultFragment(); break;
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//            AccountFragment fragment = new AccountFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.account_frame, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        setTitle(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
```

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what goes wrong?
Any exceptions or what?

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity, that hosts your fragment, be sure to add those lines:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Check this post for more info [Android onActivityResult not called from fragment](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2015/05/27/android-onactivityresult-not-called-from-fragment/)

Comment: Yeah i have that line.. but how to call from this fragment

Comment: Do you have `onActivityResult()` method overridden both in a Fragment and an Activity ?Can you post your Activity code?

Comment: Try to remove `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` call from your Fragment.onActivityResult() method and check if that works.
Do you nest your ProfileFragment inside another fragment?